# Return numeric month as string from date

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, tostring, date-formatting

I'm trying to get the numeric month as a string from a DateTime value, and instead I am getting MonthName, dayOfMonth. Here is my code:

```
string columnDate = "7/1/2003 12:00:00 AM";
string datePart = "M";
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Parse(columnDate); // 7/1/2003 12:00:00 AM as date 
dateToReturn = newDate.ToString(datePart); 
// dateToReturn is set to "July 01". It's supposed to be "7"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use newDate.Month.ToString()

Comment: dateToReturn = String.Format("{0:M}",newDate);

Comment: `DateTime.ToString()` method doesn't take a magical parameter which returns month part of current datetime. You can use `newDate.Month` as Steve said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why not simply

```
dateToReturn = newDate.Month.ToString();
```

or

```
dateToReturn = newDate.Month.ToString("D2");
```

to have the month part formatted with the leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
dateToReturn = String.Format("{0:M}",Convert.toDateTime(newDate));
```

Comment: Converting `newDate` is obsolete because it's a `DateTime` anyway.